# Are Cassandra partition keys case sensitive?

Tags: cassandra, partition, case-sensitive

I wanted to know if Cassandra partition keys are case sensitive or not

Can I create two such partition keys in Cassandra?

```
table1/key1
table1/KEY1
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, partition keys are case-sensitive - the value of the partition key is hashed using the configured hash algorithm, and this hash is used to select the node(s) on which data is stored.  If you need case-insensitive partition key, you need to do key normalization (lowercase or uppercase) in your application.

Answer (score 1):

An easy way to verify this, is by using the `token` function in CQL.

```
> SELECT key, token(key), email FROM user_profiles ;

 key      | system.token(key)    | email
----------+----------------------+------------------
 hendrix1 | -3316313890454506950 | email1@music.com
 Hendrix1 |  2207379501911492768 | jimmyh@music.com
 HENDRIX1 |  7586162484640993771 |  jimmy@music.com

(3 rows)
```

As you can see, the tokens generated for each different case string of the key are indeed different.  Hence, you will definitely want to be aware of case for string/text key values.